# ScriptUtils.readScript() with DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR is not working

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to execute a sql script from file using ScriptUtils.readScript method:

```
sql = ScriptUtils.readScript(fileReader,
                            ScriptUtils.DEFAULT_COMMENT_PREFIX,
                            ScriptUtils.DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR);

getJdbcTemplate().update(sql);
```

But I get the error **org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar** and from the logs I see that semicolon * in the sql statement is not ignored even I am using ScriptUtils.DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR why it isn't working? What's wrong here?

**Edit**: I know that I can solve this by using:

```
getJdbcTemplate().update(sql.replace(";", ""));
```

but maybe there is another solution?

**Edit2**: Here is example of sql that I need to execute:

```
INSERT
INTO MYTABLE
  (
    ID,
    MYNUMBER,
    MYVALUE
  )
 SELECT 
  ID,
  0,
  B.MYVALUE
 FROM ATABLE A,
  BTABLE B
  WHERE A.ID   = B.ID
 AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE M WHERE M.ID = A.ID
  );
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is in the file, what you are getting into variable `sql`, and what you expect to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using `ScriptUtils.readScript` the right way. The [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html) themselves state:

> Mainly for internal use within the framework.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d5ee787e1e6653257720afe31ee3f8819cd4605c/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.java#L289), it seems that all this function does is load all the lines from a file into a single string, with some logic around comments. The use of the separator in this method is minor and appears only to be relevant if there is a whitespace at the end of it.

If you want to ignore the separator, you'll need to remove it the way that you suggested (with a `replace`).

Comment: Ok, maybe you know some alternatives then for this purpose?

Comment: For the purpose of reading a file into a string? I suppose you could use [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.Reader)).